# Poly-Time TSP Algorithm if there is constant factor approximation algorithm?

Tags: np-complete, traveling-salesman

I know that a polynomial-time constant factor approximation algorithm for the general Traveling Salesman Problem does not exist unless P=NP. However, I want to prove that the TSP decision problem (is there a Hamiltonian cycle of graph with weight sum <= k?) is in P if we assume that there is an approximation algorithm that guarantees optimal solution * a (a>1). Is there a way to prove this problem, without using polynomial reduction?

Comment: Hint: take $a$ close enough to 1.

Comment: a is fixed constant in this problem. ex) 100

Comment: What does the approximation algorithm return when there is no Hamiltonian cycle?

Comment: Hamiltonian cycle always exists in TSP problem. Graph in the TSP is always complete graph with positive weights.

Comment: Are you familiar with the NP-completeness proof for TSP (the one that reduces from Hamiltonian cycle)? It might give you some ideas.